# Node expand box is not visible in Internet explorer and Chrome but is visible in firefox

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, radtreeview

I have a radtreeview in item template of a radcombobox. The parent node is visible but its expand box is not in chrome and IE but its visible in firefox.[image: Image From Firefox]

[image: Image from IE]

Am i missing something or what can i do to fix this issue.

Comment: Please provide code which is not working on chrome and ie.

Comment: This might help : [check](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/treeview/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)